# Как найти минимальное значение в массиве в Java?

Tags: java

Есть массив чисел[1,4,-2,3]. 
Как найти минимальное значение в массиве??

Answer (score 7):

По-всякому, например так:

```
    var nums = new int[] {1, 4, -2, 3};
    var min = Arrays.stream(nums).min();
    System.out.println(min.isPresent() ? min.getAsInt() : "empty array");
```

или так:

```
    var nums = new int[] {1, 4, -2, 3};
    var min = Collections.min(Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println(min);
```

или так:

```
    var nums = new int[]{1, 4, -2, 3};
    var min = nums[0];
    for (int num : nums) {
        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min);
```

Comment: var здесь из какого языка?

Comment: @Эникейщик Из Java 10

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал это более понятным способом:

```
int min = a[0] + 1;
for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
    if (a[i]< min) {
       min = a[i];
    } 
System.out.println(min);
}
```

Проходим по массиву, каждый элемент сравниваем с наименьшим.

Comment: Зачем к `a[0]` прибавлять единицу? В этом нет никакого смысла. Чем этот код понятнее третьего варианта в моём ответе? Так же обратите внимание, что лишь первый вариант, из моего ответа, корректно работает с пустым массивом. При этом он самый простой.

Comment: Для меня - а я студент - первый вариант вообще не был понятен. И что выведет при пустом массиве?

Comment: Да и цикл for ech (лично для меня) не так понятен.

Comment: При пустом массиве первый вариант моего решения выведет "empty array". Второй вариант моего решения упадёт с `NoSuchElementException`. Третий варианты моего решения, а так же ваше решение упадут с `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. В первом варианте моего решения из массива чисел создаётся `IntStream`, в котором есть метод `min()`, умеющий находить минимальное значение. Поскольку минимальное значение существует не всегда метод `min()` возвращает объект обёртку `OptionalInt`. В дальнейшем у этого объекта можно спросить `isPresent()` а есть ли там настоящий результат.

Comment: Ростислав, круто) а я придумал еще один метод)

Answer (score 0):

Еще один метод.

```
int[] mass = {1,2,3-1};
int[] mass2 = mass.clone();
Arrays.sort(mass2); 
System.out.println(mass2[0]);
```

Можно и без клонирования, если не нужен исходный массив