# Решаю задачу на java

Tags: java

Решаю следующую задачу. Реализовать программу на Java, которая для последовательности чисел, оканчивающихся на -1 выведет самую минимальную цифру, встречающуюся среди чисел последовательности.

Например:

### 345
298
456

Ответ: 2

Создал 2 варианта, но оба не работают. Я понимаю, что вводимые числа нужно разбить на цифры и только после этого определять минимум среди них. Но не знаю как реализовать.
Вариант 1:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class homework05 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = scn.nextInt();
        int min = 0;
        do {
            number = scn.nextInt();

            int digit1 = number / 100;
            int digit2 = (number % 100)/10;
            int digit3 = number % 10;

            if (digit1 < digit2 && digit1 < digit3 && digit1 > -1){
                min = digit1;
            }
            if (digit2 < digit1 && digit2 < digit3  && digit2 > -1){
                min = digit2;
            }
            if (digit3 < digit1 && digit3 < digit2 && digit3 > -1){
                min = digit3;
            }

        }while (number != -1);
        System.out.println(min);

    }
    }
```

Вариант 2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class homework05 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = scn.nextInt();
        int min = 0;
        while (number != -1) {
            int num = scn.nextInt();
            int digit1 = num / 100;
            int digit2 = (num % 100) / 10;
            int digit3 = num % 10;

            while (num != -1) {
                if (digit1 < digit2 && digit1 < digit3 && digit1 > -1) {
                    min = digit1;
                }
                if (digit2 < digit1 && digit2 < digit3 && digit2 > -1) {
                    min = digit2;
                }
                if (digit3 < digit1 && digit3 < digit2 && digit3 > -1) {
                    min = digit3;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(min);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А если считывать не числа, а строки и искать в строке минимальный символ?

Answer (score 0):

пишем в гугле **число в массив java**, третья ссылка в поиске ведёт на [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058001/Запись-цифр-числа-в-массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058001/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)
выбираем понравившийся алгоритм (ну или тот который понятен) сохраняем или запоминаем.
потом ищем алгоритм поиска -  **минимальное число в массиве java**  первая ссылка ведёт на [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887073/Как-найти-минимальное-значение-в-массиве-в-java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887073/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2-java)    выбираем понравившийся алгоритм (ну или тот который понятен) сохраняем или запоминаем.

затем создаём статик метод куда всё впихиеваем

```
static int minFromNumber(int number) {
   

 int[] arr = new int[String.valueOf(number).length()]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    int min = arr[0];
    for (int num : arr) {

        if (min > num) {
            min = num;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

проверяем на числе 345 298 456
вывод - 2
контрольная проверка, меням какую-нибудь цифру на 1, затем на 0. вроде работает...

ну вот и думаем, вызываем метод либо его содержимое копируем в класс.

как-то так.

либо следуем совету **tym32167**, и по выше описанным аглоритмам ищем как считывать не числа, а строки и искать в строке минимальный символ.

Comment: Вариант хороший, но массивы мы еще не проходили, поэтому такое решение не примут. Нужно решить через циклы, но не придумал, какое условие поставить для вложенного цикла. За ответ спасибо, познавательно.

Comment: ну тогда число в строку и пробежаться по каждому символу

Answer (score 0):

Существующий код жёстко привязан к трёхзначным числам, чего можно спокойно избежать, считывая числа во внешнем цикле, и обрабатывая каждое число во вложенном цикле.  Также при нахождении минимальной цифры 0 можно досрочно заканчивать поиски, выходя из вложенного цикла с помощью `break out`, где `out:` - метка:

```java
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int min = 10; // на случай пустой последовательности ввода

int number;

out:          // метка досрочного выхода 
while ((number = scn.nextInt()) != -1) {
    if (number == 0) { // проверить на 0 при вводе
        min = 0;
        break;
    }

    while (number > 0) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        if (digit < min) {
            min = digit;
            if (min == 0) { // проверить на 0 внутри числа
                break out;
            }
        }
        number /= 10;
    } // проверка числа закончена
} // ввод чисел закончен

if (min < 10) {
    System.out.println("Минимальная цифра: " + min);
} else {
    System.out.println("Минимальная цифра не обнаружена"); // сразу ввели -1
}
```